# How to save/load the partial model for fine-tuning/transfer-learning in TF2.1?

Tags: transfer-learning, tensorflow2.x

I would like to build my own base model and train it with big dataset. After training, I save the base model. I have another customized model and I want to load the weights of first two layers from the base model. How should I achieve it in Tensorflow 2.1.0, thanks.

Sample codes:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="" 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class BaseModel():
    def __init__(self):
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
        x = inputs
        x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
        x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)

        x = layers.Flatten()(x)

        x = layers.Dense(500, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)

        outputs = layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

        self.model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.model(inputs)

bm = BaseModel()  # the model for pretraining
bm.model.save_weights('base_model') # save the pretrained model


class MyModel():
    def __init__(self):
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
        x = inputs
        x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
        x = layers.MaxPool2D()(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)

        x = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)

        x = layers.Flatten()(x)

        x = layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)

        outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

        self.model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.model(inputs)


mm = MyModel()  # the model for my customized applications
mm.model.load_weights('base_model')  # load the pretrained model with the first two conv layers

# further fine-tuning or transfer learning
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the custom model available in TF website demonstrate the idea. Using subclassed models is little different from Keras Sequential and functional model. I have used Subclassed model to demo the idea as follows.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
```

#### base model

```
class ThreeLayerMLP(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, name=None):
    super(ThreeLayerMLP, self).__init__(name=name)
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')
    self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')
    self.pred_layer = layers.Dense(10, name='predictions')

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    x = self.dense_2(x)
    return self.pred_layer(x)

def get_model():
  return ThreeLayerMLP(name='3_layer_mlp')

base_model = get_model()

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype('float32') / 255

base_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop())
history = base_model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=64,
                    epochs=1)
#saving weights
base_model.save_weights('./base_model_weights', save_format='tf')
```

#### custom model

```
class MyCustomModel(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, name=None):
    super(MyCustomModel, self).__init__(name=name)
    self.dense_1 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_1')
    self.dense_2 = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', name='dense_2')
    self.pred_layer = layers.Dense(10, name='predictions')

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    x = self.dense_2(x)
    return self.pred_layer(x)

def get_custom_model():
  return MyCustomModel(name='my_custom_model')

my_custom_model = get_custom_model()

my_custom_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop())
```

The following step is import when the saved model has any custom_objects or custom layers in the model

```
# This initializes the variables used by the optimizers,
# as well as any stateful metric variables
my_custom_model.train_on_batch(x_train[:1], y_train[:1])

# Load the state of the old model (to load weights for all layers)
# my_custom_model.load_weights('path_to_my_weights')

layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in base_model.layers])
print(layer_dict)

# my_custom_model.trainable = True
# loading the weights from base_model
for layer in my_custom_model.layers:
  layer_name = layer.name
  #print(layer.name)
  layer.set_weights(layer_dict[layer_name].get_weights())
```